# How to fix type is missing from following property in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I worked for the past 2 years on angular, but this is the first time I am using the interface. I face a small issue added below.

> Type 'MatTableDataSource<Tasks[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Tasks[][]': length, pop, push, concat, and 24 more.ts(2740)

Please help me to solve this small issue. Below is my code.

```
export interface Tasks {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  assignedTo: Array<Team>,
  status: string;
}
```

**Service**

```
 getTasks(): Observable<Tasks[]> {
    return this.http.get<Tasks[]>(`${environment.API_URL}tasks`).pipe(
      map(data => {
        return data;
      })
    )
  }
```

**component file**

```
getTasks() {
    this.taskService.getTasks().subscribe(response => {
      // this.tasks = response;
      console.log(response)
      if (this.tasks) {
        this.dataSource.data = new MatTableDataSource<Tasks[]>(response)
      }
      console.log(this.tasks)
    })
  }
```

[image]

Any solution is appreciated!

Comment: Show your Tasks interface please.

Comment: `this.dataSource.data = response`. You dont need to create again the dataSource.

Comment: @hawks still getting same error

Comment: @ShyamJoshi interface added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to set the type of `MatTableDataSource` as `Tasks[]`. Internally `MatTableDataSource` treats your type as T[].

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Tasks>() // Tasks represents each row of the mat-table

getTasks() {
  // your code
  this.dataSource.data = response
}
```

I think you should rename your interface to `Task` and not `Tasks`. Because it represents only one Task.

Answer (score 1):

Add this way -

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Tasks>(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<Tasks>

dataSource.data = response
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).